# Google Webmaster Tools : removing URL tool has removed the wrong url from index

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I've asked for the following url to be removed (the entire directory):

www.mydomain.com/blog/some-article/attachment/

but this morning to my surprise the url www.mydomain.com/blog/some-article/ is no longer indexed - I can see that from the number of indexed pages in my sitemap and also when I do:

info:www.mydomain.com/blog/some-article/  because nothing is found.

That is not what I expected. Should I reintegrate the url that I removed from the index, or is it just a temporary glitch ?

Comment: Most likely Google has decided to drop the URL. Does the attachment page have a canonical set to the parent? What is the attachment? file type?

Comment: attachment is a folder which contains images that are attached to a wordpress page. Now that you say it, there was a 301 on attachment to the parent post. Could that be the reason ?

Comment: Yes... no need to redirect those pages or use robots. Simply use noindex on attachment pages.

Comment: they are, but unattached images are not. This is why I wanted to remove the url from google index

Comment: You've confused me. What are you trying to do? do you want Google indexing your images in Google image search? If you want images within Google's image index then you use noindex on attachment pages, nothing more, then wait... Google will remove those pages when it crawls them, no need to manually remove anything unless you have sensitive pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well well well....

all is fine now, the urls are showing when I type info:url

last night I've noticed that the number of indexed urls in my sitemap had dropped and I thought it was related to that.

**It turns out it is a bug in search console :** 
https://twitter.com/methode/status/634308230940872704